# JQuery UI multiselect binding removed after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, multi-select

I have a page that is being loaded on ajax request. There is 2 dropdown fields that are attached to JQuery UI Multiselect http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/
**It is working fine. Actual problem is that when I save the form, again ajax content refreshes and multiselect events gone. It is happening just on form submit. The form is being saved by calling the same ajax request.**

Multiselect binding events are being attached in **document ready** and defined within ajax content file. I also used **`.on()`** in JQuery but in vain. I am using jquery 1.10.3
Here is multiselect binding code

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("#branch").multiselect({
            header: I18n.t("Choose only FOUR industries!"),
            click: function(e, ui){
                // some stuff                    
            }
        }); 
    });
```

You can have view the problem by going to http://storexpo-dev.coeus-solutions.de/ , using *ghi@jkl.com* as username and *demo123* as password.
Once logged in, go to *Profil bearbeiten* and then on Company Information tab and save the form.

Comment: This call is failing http://storexpo-dev.coeus-solutions.de/user/; I think can cause the issue, but start to check from here

Comment: Are you generating new select box in php and replacing the select field? Show us how you are posting the form. Did you try this:
 $("body").on("event","#element",function(){});

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I will check it but this is also failing in simple scenario when form is not being saved, just loading page.

Comment: @Zohaib Yeah I tried. The same content is refreshed on form submission. The same action called.

Comment: @Bilal try refreshing the multiselect `$("#branch").multiselect("refresh");` or destroy the existing and reinitialize it i.e. `$("#branch").multiselect('destroy');
$("#branch").multiselect();

Comment: already tried not working. The only problem occurs on saving form ajax request otherwise its fine. Note that both ajax requests are same and render same html